# Effective algorithm for subset sum search problem based on decision problem of subset sum

Tags: combinatorics, computational-complexity

Let us assume that we know the polynomial algorithm for the subset sum decision problem. It return YES (when there is some sub-set summing up to $k$) or NO (when it subset does not exist).

How can we most efficiently build an algorithm based on such an algorithm that will return a subset that adds up to $k$?

What is the complexity of such an algorithm?

Intuitively, it seems possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we already know that $S$ has a subset that adds up to $k$.

Pick an element $n \in S$ and ask whether $S \setminus \{n\}$ has the desired property.  If so, return a subset of $S \setminus \{n\}$ that adds up to $k$; otherwise $n$ is an essential element of the solution.  Return the union of $\{n\}$ and a subset of $S \setminus \{n\}$ that adds up to $k-n$ (which is guaranteed to exist).

The oracle is called at most $|S|$ times.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the summands come from set $S$; you can assume all the elements of $S$ are less than $k$.

The standard recursive algorithm that loops on $n \in S$ and tries to complete the sum by looking for the subset sum $k -n$ using numbers you haven't yet tried can be speeded up by invoking your oracle before continuing the recursion.

It's not clear to me how much this will help performance.